# @Html.TextboxFor Contiene un valor pero no lo muestra en la vista

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Tengo un inconveniente mostrando un dato con Razor debido a que el dato viene del modelo y lo muestro a través de Razor del siguiente modo:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Identificacion, new { @class = "question"})
```

Cuando la vista se renderiza en campo aparentemente está vacío pero si utilizo el inspector de elementos este si contiene el valor que proviene del modelo así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero el campo se ve de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A qué se debe esto? Como paréntesis y si influye de algo en el modelo el campo es de tipo `Long`

Comment: Que contiene la clase CSS `question`?

Comment: Contiene estilos de fuente, tamaño, y la línea que se ve en el `input`, como tal si la remuevo,igual no muestra ningún dato pero si en Value justo como en la imagen.

Comment: agrega el codigo del estilo a tu pregunta y como esta declarado el campo Identificacion?

Comment: solo para estar seguros que se agrega texto al valor intenta: @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Identificacion, new { @class = "question", Value=String.Format("{0:C}",model.Identificacion) })

Comment: Tienes que poner  el contexto   input : como se declara (si tiene anotaciones) el dato asociado  en el modelo, los contenedores padre, y sus atributosl que ayuden al análisis de lo contrario vamos a estar tanteando para ver si en alguna le damos.

Comment: Por último ¿ el problema ocurre en todos los  navegadores?

Comment: Gracias por su colaboración el error era muy mínimo en una declaración de JavaScript estaba poniendo en null los valores sin haberme percatado.